# Getting User Input in React Js in Fetch statement

Tags: html, reactjs, api

I have created a code for fetching weather data from api. Here in the link, I have given a Place q=chennai. I need to change this place field depends on user. that is I want to get this location from user. How can I do this using react

````
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';

const Home1=()=>{
    const[info,setInfo]=useState({
        name:"loading !!",
        temp:"loading",
        humidity:"loading",
        desc:"loading",
    })
    useEffect(()=>
    {
        getWeather()
    })
    const getWeather=()=>
    {
        fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=chennai&appid=bd2d67a73f2dc8279......')
        .then(data=>data.json())
        .then(results=>{
           //console.log(results)
           setInfo({
               name:results.name,
               temp:results.main.temp,
               humidity:results.main.humidity,
               desc:results.weather[0].description,
           })
        })
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Weather API</h1>
            <div>
                 Place:{info.name} <br/>
                 Temperature:{info.temp} <br/>
                 Humidity:{info.humidity} <br/>
                 Description: {info.desc}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home1;```

Can somebody help me to do this ?
````

Comment: The question is I want to get the location from user instead of giving hardcode in link

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the input from the user and write a onChange event handler. Once you get the input you can call the getWeather function and pass the value you got from the user to the function. Here is the solution -

```html
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';

const Home1=()=>{
    const[info,setInfo]=useState({
        name:"loading !!",
        temp:"loading",
        humidity:"loading",
        desc:"loading",
    })

    const [inputValue , setInputValue] = useState("");
    useEffect(()=>
    {
        getWeather("chennai")
    })
    const getWeather=(value)=>
    {
        fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${value}&appid=bd2d67a73f2dc8279......`)
        .then(data=>data.json())
        .then(results=>{
           //console.log(results)
           setInfo({
               name:results.name,
               temp:results.main.temp,
               humidity:results.main.humidity,
               desc:results.weather[0].description,
           })
        })
    }

  const handleInputChange = event =>{
        let inputValue = event.target.value;
        console.log(event.target.value); // You will the value here. you can simply pass the value to the function
        setInputValue(inputValue);
        getWeather(inputValue);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Weather API</h1>
            <div>
                 Place:{info.name} <br/>
                 Temperature:{info.temp} <br/>
                 Humidity:{info.humidity} <br/>
                 Description: {info.desc}
                 <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home1;
```

Comment: Failed to compile
src\components\APICALL.js
  Line 11:5:   'handleChange' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 21:68:  Unexpected use of 'location'   no-restricted-globals

src\components\stackoveripget.js
  Line 15:20:  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Got this error while doing handleInputChange

Answer (score 0):

You can use a controlled input to gives to the user the possibility to choose the location.

```js
const [city, setCity] = useState("chennai") // Initialize city default value

...

useEffect(()=> { getWeather(city) }, [city])
// Add the city as dependency to your effect and pass the value to getWeather method

...

fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=bd2d67a73f2dc8279......`)
// Make the url to fetch a template string so you can inject the city state in it

...

<input type="text" value={city} onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)} />
// Add the input with onChange method
```

If you want to know more about controlled input in React this is the doc related page https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Thanks. But it was loading correctly in the first time. but after entering the value in input field it was throwing the error **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined**  How to handle this error. I have modified the changes you said.

Comment: Yes, it's because now you make a request every time the user change the input. For some values the weather data not exist and the "results" variable return 404 error code. See "API errors" in the doc https://openweathermap.org/faq . You have to handle that error. Put an if statement before the setInfo method and check the validity of the response